# How to force using internet from 3G even when connected to WIFI?

Tags: android, android-wifi, 3g

I'm working on an application that connects to a hardware device using WIFI.
Basically, the device creates a wifi network that is used to communicate with it.

The problem is that this device is not a router and does not provide an internet connection. So when I connected to this device using the wifi connection I lose all network capabilities from my Android device. I can't update the server or do any other task that requires an internet connection.

On iPhone in this case, the device can recognize the fact that the WIFI does not provide a connection to the network and switches automatically to use the 3g connection.

**So the question is:** Is there a way to force network traffic to go through the 3G connection even when I have WIFI connection established?

Comment: Why don't you just turn off wi-fi on the device?

Comment: @Tharkius Because I need it to continue communicating with the hardware device.

Comment: There are dozens of questions here on SO asking for the same, I have not seen any working answer. I assume that you need root permissions and have to modifying the Android system to make it work.

Comment: What Android version are you running? This should be default behavior since Lollipop: https://www.androidpolice.com/2014/10/18/lollipop-feature-spotlight-android-now-defaults-to-mobile-data-when-wi-fi-has-no-internet-access-signal-icon-adds-a-for-no-connection/

Comment: @Robert I searched and did not find any related questions, I might have missed it but didn't see any.

Comment: Seems at least for some devices it was possible: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=46274571&postcount=6

Comment: @VitorM.Barbosa I'm running Galaxy 6S with Nugat, and it's not the default behavoir.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this method on the application below to make the connection to happen only with 3G.

> public boolean requestRouteToHost (int networkType, int hostAddress).

Pass the parameters for Network type and the host address to specify the connection type and target endpoint.

Comment: Could you please provide more information on how this should be used? I can't find decent code examples.